# Send XML data to server using jQuery $.post

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, xml

I was browsing through other questions and posts but couldn't find the answer.

I need to send data to PHP file which saves the data to the server. Some of the data is just string variables and one of the variables is XML data. I tried to do it with the following code:

```
$.post(
    "save.php",
    { 
        userId: _UserId, 
        pName: _pName, 
        pId: _pId, 
        xml: $(_xml).find("main").text()
    },
    function () { 
        console.log("Saved"); 
    }
);
```

So `_xml` is an XML document and I am trying to save the entire XML in the server. The POST works but the problem is that it saves only the text, without the `<>` brackets.

How do I properly send the XML data to the server? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

> The POST works but the problem is that it saves only the text, without the <> brackets.

Try using `html()` instead. I know the name may be incorrect in this instance, but the underlying method will not remove elements contained within the current.

```
xml: $(_xml).find("main").html()
```

Comment: `_xml` doesn't need to be a DOM element for it to work, nor does it need to contain valid HTML. Why does it not work?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
$.ajax({
type : "POST",
url : "Save.php",
data : {
    method : "Save",
    userId: _UserId, 
    pName: _pName, 
    pId: _pId, 
    xml: escape(xmlString)
},
dataType : "json",
cache : false,
success : function(data) {
// Process return status data here
}
});
```

Note: You need to decode the xml string at server side.

Comment: Thanks but how do I add the rest of my variables to your function? (userId, pName, pId)

Comment: I have modified the snippet. Please have a look.

Comment: Before trying your answer I was able to post the XML with the brackets by using this function: `function XmlSerialize(xml) {
  var s;
  if (typeof XMLSerializer === "function") {
    var x = new XMLSerializer();
    s = x.serializeToString(xml);
  } else {
    s = xml.xml;
  }
  return s
}`

Comment: I have other problem now: the XML string which returns from the server when I read it is not full and cut in the middle. Is there a length restriction somewhere? In JS, PHP or mySql?